# How to change this pseudo class with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following SVG element which is related to some other stuff

```
<text x="370.9472783496851" y="141.05272165031482" text-anchor="middle" font="10px &quot;Arial&quot;" stroke="none" fill="#000000" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: middle; font: 10px Arial;" class="wheelnav-wheelDiv-title-basic-1" id="wheelnav-wheelDiv-title-1" transform="matrix(0.7071,-0.7071,0.7071,0.7071,8.7932,303.3224)" stroke-width="1.0360904852357105"><tspan dy="3.1620966503148225" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Multiformer II</tspan></text>
```

So as you can see, there is a tspan element inside the text element and I am using the css style sheet to give it a specific style like this:

```
[class|=wheelnav-wheelDiv-title-basic]>tspan {
    fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    stroke: none;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: Lato;
}
```

and it works fine, but I want to change the style of the tspan while the program is running. I mean with JS, I've tried the following:

```
for(let i=0;i<3;i++){
                        let element_class = 'wheelnav-wheelDiv-title-basic-'+i;
                        let element = document.getElementsByClassName(element_class).item(0);
                        console.log(element);
                    }
```

but it gives me that the HTMLCollection is empty (null), so there is no children.

### Edit

By the way I have the other elements like :

wheelnav-wheelDiv-title-basic-0
wheelnav-wheelDiv-title-basic-2

### Bug found

It turns out that I was trying to get the elements from the DOM before it is been created and that is why it was returning null.

Comment: really, your code works fine: `null
<text x=​"370.9472783496851" ... </text>​
null`

Comment: what do you mean? it works fine indeed, but I want to change the style of the tspan from the Js, am I clear? :)

Answer (score 2):

In your SVG example you have only an element with the class:

```
"wheelnav-wheelDiv-title-basic-1"
```

When you are executing your for loop the first element for you are looking for is the one who has the class:

```
"wheelnav-wheelDiv-title-basic-**0**"
```

That's why you are getting HTMLCollection as empty and then you are getting the exception on `.item(0)`.

Comment: thx for the feedback but I've posted a part of the SVG and actually I have the 0 and the 2 elements.

Comment: guys this is not the problem, pls some other ideas

Comment: I have just tested your code in browser and it works fine for me considering that exist the elements with those classes. May I know if it crash when index is 0? Or you get any on console. Also, which browser are you using?

Comment: hi Brank, I am using Chrome and it gives me null but in the console I still can navigate to the tspan element but when am trying to change the style using the JS it gives me the following: ' Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined',what do you think, thx

Comment: Can you tell us how are you trying to assign the backgroundColor property?

Comment: like this:  element[0].style.backgroundColor = 'red'; inside the for loop

Comment: You cannot do that due to element is already the item that you are going to modify, you must do element.style.backgroundColor = 'red'

Comment: I've just tried it and unfortunatlly it still doesn't work